# Comparing Nested Python dict with list and dict

Tags: python, git, list, dictionary

*I've seen similar questions but none that exactly match what I'm doing and I believe other developers might face same issue if they are working with MongoDB.*

I'm looking to compare two nested dict objects with dict and arrays and return a dict with additions and deletion (like you would git diff two files)

Here is what I have so far:

```
def dict_diff(alpha, beta, recurse_adds=False, recurse_dels=False):
    """
    :return: differences between two python dict with adds and dels
    example:
    (This is the expected output)
    {
        'adds': 
        {
            'specific_hours': [{'ends_at': '2015-12-25'}],
        }
        'dels': 
        {
            'specific_hours': [{'ends_at': '2015-12-24'}],
            'subscription_products': {'review_management': {'thiswillbedeleted': 'deleteme'}}
        }
    }
    """
    if type(alpha) is dict and type(beta) is dict:
        a_keys = alpha.keys()
        b_keys = beta.keys()
        dels = {}
        adds = {}
        for key in a_keys:
            if type(alpha[key]) is list:
                if alpha[key] != beta[key]:
                    adds[key] = dict_diff(alpha[key], beta[key], recurse_adds=True)
                    dels[key] = dict_diff(alpha[key], beta[key], recurse_dels=True)
            elif type(alpha[key]) is dict:
                if alpha[key] != beta[key]:
                    adds[key] = dict_diff(alpha[key], beta[key], recurse_adds=True)
                    dels[key] = dict_diff(alpha[key], beta[key], recurse_dels=True)
            elif key not in b_keys:
                dels[key] = alpha[key]
            elif alpha[key] != beta[key]:
                adds[key] = beta[key]
                dels[key] = alpha[key]

        for key in b_keys:
            if key not in a_keys:
                adds[key] = beta[key]

    elif type(alpha) is list and type(beta) is list:
        index = 0
        adds=[]
        dels=[]
        for elem in alpha:
            if alpha[index] != beta[index]:
                dels.append(alpha[index])
                adds.append(beta[index])
                # print('update', adds, dels)
            index+=1
    else:
        raise Exception("dict_diff function can only get dict objects")

    if recurse_adds:
        if bool(adds):
            return adds
        return {}
    if recurse_dels:
        if bool(dels):
            return dels
        return {}
    return {'adds': adds, 'dels': dels}
```

The result I'm getting now is:

```html
{'adds': {'specific_hours': [{'ends_at': '2015-12-24',
                              'open_hours': ['07:30-11:30', '12:30-21:30'],
                              'starts_at': '2015-12-22'},
                             {'ends_at': '2015-01-03',
                              'open_hours': ['07:30-11:30'],
                              'starts_at': '2015-01-0'}],
          'subscription_products': {'review_management': {}}},
 'dels': {'specific_hours': [{'ends_at': '2015-12-24',
                              'open_hours': ['07:30-11:30', '12:30-21:30'],
                              'starts_at': '2015-12-2'},
                             {'ends_at': '2015-01-03',
                              'open_hours': ['07:30-11:30'],
                              'starts_at': '2015-01-0'}],
          'subscription_products': {'review_management': {'thiswillbedeleted': 'deleteme'}}}}
```

And this is the two objects I'm trying to compare:

```
alpha = {
    'specific_hours': [
                        {
                            "starts_at": "2015-12-2",
                            "ends_at": "2015-12-24",
                            "open_hours": [
                                "07:30-11:30",
                                "12:30-21:30"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "starts_at": "2015-01-0",
                            "ends_at": "2015-01-03",
                            "open_hours": [
                                "07:30-11:30"
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
'subscription_products': {'presence_management': 
                            {'expiration_date': 1953291600,
                            'payment_type': {
                                    'free': 'iamfree',
                                    'test': "test",
                                    },
                            },
                        'review_management': 
                            {'expiration_date': 1511799660,
                            'payment_type': {
                                    'free': 'iamfree',
                                    'test': "test",
                                    },
                            'thiswillbedeleted': "deleteme",
                            }
                        },
}

beta = {
    'specific_hours': [
                        {
                            "starts_at": "2015-12-22",
                            "ends_at": "2015-12-24",
                            "open_hours": [
                                "07:30-11:30",
                                "12:30-21:30"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "starts_at": "2015-01-0",
                            "ends_at": "2015-01-03",
                            "open_hours": [
                                "07:30-11:30"
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
'subscription_products': {'presence_management': 
                            {'expiration_date': 1953291600,
                            'payment_type': {
                                    'free': 'iamfree',
                                    'test': "test",
                                    },
                            },
                        'review_management': 
                            {'expiration_date': 1511799660,
                            'payment_type': {
                                    'free': 'iamfree',
                                    'test': "test",
                                    },
                            }
                        },
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes sorry hit enter before finishing my post

Comment: So you've shown us your code, and sample input, but you haven't told us what's not working. Do you get the wrong output (what's wrong?) or an error (show the exception traceback)?

Comment: @TomDalton thank you for your comment, I've updated my questions with current output and expected one

Comment: I don't have the time to write a complete example, but quite some redundancy can get rid of by using sets and set difference between the two.